# Can you tell me why the second in incrementing in even numbers in the stopwatch?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to create a stopwatch, when I run it, it's counting the seconds in even numbers like 0 - 2 - 4 - 6....... I don't understand why.

I don't find any error in the code. if anyone can help, it would be helpful

```
export default function Stopwatch() {
    let [ispaused,setIspaused ] = useState(false);
    let [seconds, setSeconds] = useState (0);

    let secondsref = useRef(seconds)
    let ispausedRef = useRef(ispaused);
    let watch = useRef(0);
    
    let initTicker= ()=>{
        ispausedRef.current = true
        setIspaused(true);
        
      }
      let stopTicker=()=>{
        ispausedRef.current = false
        setIspaused(false)
        //setSecondsleft(secondsleftRef.current);
      }
      
      let resethndler = ()=>{
        setIspaused(false)
        ispausedRef.current = false;
        secondsref.current=0;
        setSeconds(0);
        
      }

      let Tick = ()=>{
        secondsref.current+=1;
        setSeconds(secondsref.current);
}

 useEffect(()=>{
    
watch.current = setInterval(()=>{
    if (!ispausedRef.current){
        return;
        }
    Tick();
},1000)
 },[])     

let percantage = ((seconds%60)/60)*100

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='stopwatch'>
          
          <CircularProgressbar
          ssbar value={percantage} text={`0${parseInt(seconds/60)}`.slice(-2)+ ":" +`0${seconds%60}`.slice(-2)} />
          
          </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fasten your seat belt it will be fun! :)

I assume you're using `<StrictMode>`. This mode will mount / unmount / remount your components to identify potential issues in lifecycle. Only on development environment. You can read more about it from React documentation.

So once that is said, your component is in fact mounted **twice** so you're creating 2 intervals. And as React batches `setState`, it seems to count numbers 2 by 2. But it's in fact 2 different intervals.

So solution here is in your `useEffect`, which must return a cleanup function, which will destroy your interval

```js
useEffect(() => {
  ...
  return () => clearInterval(watch.current)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

As @dbuchet said, it may be because of `<StrictMode>`.

I've made a (bit simplified) version in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-lake-xh2kjb?file=/src/Stopwatch.js). Notice the commented out `StrictMode` in `index.js`. The counter works correct.